# Filtering the usergroups loaded in com_config

Tags: user-groups

Following my [previous post](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1086/many-usergroups-slow-down-sections-of-the-website), trying to make the load of config component lighter. Since, the majority of my usergroups are children of the registered usergroup and inherit the same permissions, I don't need them to get loaded in com_config.

As a workaround, I am looking for a way to filter them out, by hacking the core code. I tried with a where in the `getUserGroups()` function in : `/administrator/components/com_config/models/fields/filters.php`, as well in

```
`/administrator/components/com_config/model/fields/filters.php` .
```

The function became like:

```
protected function getUserGroups()
    {
        // Get a database object.
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        // Get the user groups from the database.
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('a.id AS value, a.title AS text, COUNT(DISTINCT b.id) AS level');
        $query->from('#__usergroups AS a');
        $query->join('LEFT', '#__usergroups AS b on a.lft > b.lft AND a.rgt < b.rgt');
        $query->where('a.parent_id != 2');
        $query->group('a.id, a.title, a.lft');
        $query->order('a.lft ASC');
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $options = $db->loadObjectList();
        return $options;
    }
```

But these changes seem to have no effect in the groups loading of the com_config.
I did the same change in  `/libraries/joomla/form/fields/rules.php`, and this filters out those groups. But I am afraid that this might act globally in what u.groups Joomla will see, affecting some of the components that I need to see those u.groups.

At first, why the hack on the com_config `getUsergroups()` function has no effect ?
What should I do in order to achieve my filtering there ? 
Secondly, I am right to consider that my second modification will hide those u.groups from everywhere in Joomla ?

Comment: Fixed it the soluution can be found in here.
http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/6955/3470

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by hacking the rules.php inside:

> /libraries/joomla/form/fields/rules.php

As it is documented inside the file, this is a form class for assigning permissions to groups for a given asset.

The `getUserGroups()` in the com_config seems to do nothing for permissions groups load, but it is used for the groups in the filters section (obviously).

Checking in com_users, I can still see my extra usergroups and probably I will still have the required access for my other needs.

So in my case, this small core hack will keep me going, till Joomla comes out with a better solution. Of course it is not maintainable an I should manually re-do this after any updates.