# How to add and show user specific content and files?

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, joomla-user-groups, features

How can I add user-specific files and content for each user as side-administrator?
And how can I be sure that only the user I've added the content for can see it?

**Example:**

User A --> A_invoice_07/15.pdf and A_invoice_08/15.pdf

User B --> B_invoice_07/15.pdf and B_invoice_08/15.pdf

So User A should only see his invoices and the same with User B.

Comment: Solutions exist, but your requirements are too broad. Most likely some extensions will do what you want. Which extensions is subject of what you are building. Please be more specific about your project requirements.

Comment: Answered on post below :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need special extensions that provide specific functionality.

I see you mention invoices, are you building an e-shop?

Most e-commerce extensions provide this kind of functionality by default, so each user has access to his personal profile data... e.g. address, orders, invoices etc.

> Solutions exist, but your requirements are too broad. Most likely some extensions will do what you want. Which extensions is subject of
>   what you are building. Please be more specific about your project
>   requirements.

Always the answer to questions like this, is to check at [**JED**](http://extensions.joomla.org/) for the extension with the features required.

#### Relative JED categories:

- **[File Management Extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/tags/file-management)**
- **[Downloads Extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/tags/downloads)**
- **[Google Search: Joomla User personal files extension](https://www.google.gr/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=joomla+user+personal+files+extension&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=cQfXVaPvI8fD8gfVrIqADw)**
- **[Extranet Extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-access/extranet)**

Comment: No I'm not building an e-shop. I just want to have an area on my website where my customers can login and have access to there last invoices, for download it again. At the moment they can login or register... But I dont know how I can add specific content to them

Comment: @Woody:: updated answer : Check in JED...  see the links above

Comment: Extranet is the solution... Thx :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are selecting content manually, you could add one group in register permission on each user. 
After this you can set the content to specific user Group. 
With this config you won't need any specific extension.

Comment: This in theory could be a creative solution, but practically creating a user group for each user would be an overkill. That's not the real purpose of the usergroups and Joomla is [**not handling very well a high number of usergroups**](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1086/many-usergroups-slow-down-sections-of-the-website). Extensions is the proper way to extend functionality and add new features on a site, when the core is not providing them.