# Upload form to upload files and filter the public view based on category

Tags: joomla-3.x, form, category, file-upload

I am looking for an extension or a way to allow users to upload their documents based on the category e.g.

a User will upload food recipe document (pdf/doc) in the category of "Chinese" or "Maxican".

Now if some one would click Mixican then all the uploaded documents will be displayed in link so the user could download..

Comment: Have you looked around the Joomla Extensions Directory for file management extensions?

Comment: [**Recently someone has asked for similar functionality**](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/12254/how-to-add-and-show-user-specific-content-and-files/12255#12255) - Usually for such questions, the first thing to do is search in JED.