# Joomla - Moodle Integration - User relationships in Joomdle

Tags: user, groups, integration

I'm building a hybrid Joomla / Moodle system using [Joomdle](http://www.joomdle.com/) to integrate the two platforms.

The system will be used by staff in a large organisation. In Joomla, users will be divided into groups representing the regional team structure. Each team will have one supervisor or team leader who will have access to create group-specific content in Joomla for his team.

So far, so easy. Now the difficult part is getting that structure to map over to Moodle.

There will be a bunch of courses in the Moodle system, which any logged in user will be able to take. But the supervisor needs to have access to view the course history and scores for his team.

Moodle has a parent-child structure that would seem to fit the bill, and Joomdle does seem to have some integration with it but I can't work out how to link it with the Joomla group structure I have in mind.

Can anyone give me some guidance here? How can I get this set up? Or is there another way to achieve the same goals?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly an answer to the integration question...

I had worked with a Joomla - Moodle integration some years ago (it was on Joomla 1.5), and to be honest I can't even remember if that was with Joomldle (I think it was not). So presently I do not actually have a recent ground-knowledge for the ins/outs of their integration with Joomdle...

But with a quick look at **Joomdle features**, I found the **[User Profiles Synchronization feature](http://www.joomdle.com/features#centralised_profiles)**, which seems to be what you are looking for.

Now... Regarding the Joomla users/usergroups structure you have in mind, if these are going to be many, I would suggest to look for a different system (like user memberships/grouping) and within this to handle what content each user will be able to read/write.

In Joomla you would keep a main and as simplest as it gets, usergroups hierarchy, like :

```
|->Supervisors (editors)
  |-> Team members (registered readers)
```

And then in the 3rd party membership/access component, you would create any kind of groups/teams with their access to specific content. Otherwise, all these different usergroups and their ACL might become very cumbersome to manage.

**Joomdle User Profiles Sync feature**, claims to provide out of the box compatibility with a few more 3rd party components.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. Some useful thoughts there. The exact hierarchy of the groups is still open (there are several hundred teams, so I agree it could be cumbersome!). The key thing here is that a supervisor should only be able to see his team members' results and no others, so there has to be a way to assign which team the supervisor belongs to and have that reflect in both Joomla and Moodle. But I'm really struggling to work it out.

Comment: @Simba - if there are several hundreds usergroups, I think you wouldn't be able to even manage the usergroups anyhow - read this issue here: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1086/many-usergroups-slow-down-sections-of-the-website

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the heads-up there. It looks like there are solutions/work-arounds, but before I get too deeply entrenched on that route, are there any alternative ways you can suggest that I could create my team structure?